# Disabling interaction in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a silly problem with an OpenLayers Map where I want to show a non-interactive picture on one site, where all clicks and such are disabled. I've tried capturing the clicks on the element but OpenLayers seems to still be able to get these events which makes the map interactive. There should be a simple solution to this but I can't figure it out.

Setting the control property to the empty array does not have any effect on the interaction.

Edit: We could not find a way to do this easily on an already existing map, so what we did was to re-use the old map initiation code in this new page, with added parameters that can remove all controls upon the creation and initiation of the map.

Answer (score 0):

*Setting the control property to the empty array does not have any effect on the interaction.*

Wierd, this should do the trick:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {controls: []});
```